# Qt closing tray icon after application stops

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt4, trayicon

I've a little problem with tray icon under windows. After my Qt application stopps (normal exit) the icon still remains in system bar. It disapears only when I move mouse cursor over it. I tried to hide it in the destructor of my window but it fails: I tried `.setVisible(false)`.

Any ideas? Thanks.

P.S. I remember I had the same problem with SWT/Java.

Comment: why would you call `setVisible(false)` rather than just destroying the widget?

Comment: How do you exit your application?

Comment: @David: I used setVisible(false) because this function couses trayicon to disappear. AFAIK qt will destroy the widget anyway. And I tried to destroy traicon with delete operator.

Comment: @atamanroman: Normal exit. I press the [x] button in the window header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't hide it in the destructor. It will likely be an invalid reference at that point. I would put it in where your event for "Exit" happens.

Comment: Good idea :) I reimplemented closeEvent member function and called setVisible(false) to hide the icon before exit.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not able to call it from a destructor, you could connect the [`QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit) signal to the [`QSystemTrayIcon::hide()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html#hide) slot.